# finite state machine & avoiding metastability

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to do an electronic dice using fsm as well as avoiding metastability in the process. so I've written this code

```
 library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Dice is 
 port( clk       : in std_logic; -- clock
       reset     : in std_logic;
         key_in    : in std_logic;  -- key to be preesed to change state 
         seven_seg : out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0)
      );
 end Dice;

architecture rulling of Dice is

  constant s_one   : std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "1111001";
  constant s_two   : std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0100100";
  constant s_three : std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0110000";
  constant s_four  : std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0011001";
  constant s_five  : std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0010010";
  constant s_six   : std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "0000010";
  signal   state   : std_logic_vector (6 downto 0) := "1111001";
  signal Metastable  : std_logic;
  signal stablee     : std_logic;
begin 

    fsm : process(clk,reset)
    begin 
        if reset = '1' then 
         --Metastable <= '0';
         --stablee <= '0';
         --state <= s_one;
         seven_seg <= s_one;
        else 
            if rising_edge(clk) then
                Metastable <= key_in;
                stablee <= Metastable;

            case state is 
                when s_one =>
                seven_seg <= s_one;  -- writing my OFL (output function logic) what to do inside the state!
                    if (stablee = '0') then 
                        state <= s_two;   -- define my NSL (nest state logic) what conditons there is to change state! 
                    else 
                        state <= s_one;
                    end if; -- ofl

               when s_two =>
                      seven_seg <= s_two; 
                    if (stablee = '0') then 
                        state <= s_three;
                  else 
                        state <= s_two;         
                    end if; 

              when s_three =>
                      seven_seg <= s_three; 
                    if (stablee = '0') then 
                        state <= s_four;     
                    else 
                        state <= s_three;
                    end if; 

               when s_four =>
                      seven_seg <= s_four; 
                    if (stablee = '0') then 
                        state <= s_five;     
                    else 
                        state <= s_four;
                    end if;

               when s_five =>
                      seven_seg <= s_five; 
                    if (stablee = '0') then 
                        state <= s_six;  
                    else 
                        state <= s_five;
                    end if; 

               when s_six =>
                      seven_seg <= s_six; 
                    if (stablee = '0') then 
                        state <= s_one;  
                    else 
                        state <= s_six;
                    end if;     

                when others =>
                       state <= s_one;
                         seven_seg <= s_one;
            end case;
        end if;
     end if;
    end process fsm;
end rulling;
```

for metastability I'm implementing this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwzon.png)

My question is when i press the debounced button witch is low active for the key_in nothing happens! but when I press the reset button and press key_in its move throw the states. Im really new to VHDL so any help appreciated.

Comment: Is your reset button low-active? Does it have a pull up resistor?

Comment: Ya its low active ! im using de1 altera fpga

Comment: Your need to negate reset because your button is low-active but your reset condition is high-active (which is good!) ...

Comment: In a matter of fact I did , but then the reset button always reset to state s_three when being pressed! one more thing when I run Modelsim and give commands (seven_seg & Metastable  & stable )  are undefined for som reasons until som clock cycles

Comment: Please show us your testbench.

Comment: You are not resetting all signals in the clocked process. The way you wrote it will introduce clock gates. Also: you need to synchronize *and debounce* **all** button inputs. Including the reset button.

Comment: would you please like to explain more !:) @JHBonarius

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164644/how-to-count-pressed-keys-on-fpga-spartan-board/45165202#45165202).