# Why the procedure doesn't see the variable?

Tags: variables, vhdl, procedure, xilinx-ise

I'm using Xilinx ISE to create a VHDL project.
I'm trying to add values to an integer variable.

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity vending2_mod is
Port ( button1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
       button2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
       button3 : in  STD_LOGIC;
       button4 : in  STD_LOGIC;
       coin : in integer;
       disp : out string(1 to 16);
       prodOut : out integer);

    shared variable credits : integer := 0;

    procedure addCredits ( c : in integer ) is
        begin
                credits := credits + c; -- Signal is not defined : 'credits'.
        end addCredits;
-- additional code
end vending2_mod;

architecture Behavioral of vending2_mod is
    begin

acceptCredit: process (coin)
    begin
            addCredits(coin);
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Yet when I try to Synthesize (XST) the project, I'm getting an error to the line I've written it as a comment. The `credits` is not a signal, it is a variable; what gives the error?
Saving gives no errors, since the syntax seems to be correct.

Comment: Show a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This isn't a valid entity declaration, `mod` is a reserved word. It's  valid VHDL if you change the entity name to say `modu` in both places.  Your version of Synplify doesn't appear to support this shared variable declaration (or use). `credits` should be initialized.

Comment: @user1155120 I simplified the names when posting the question, I didn't realize it's a reserved word. I've updated it with proper names and additional details.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: I would be very surprised to see a synthesis tool as old as XST supporting shared variables. (Integer ports should be just fine however). Why are you not using a signal here, to get the well defined (and synthesisable) semantics of signal updating? (Hint : you really want to update your signal in a clocked process)

Comment: You cannot expect the synthesis software to correctly implement just any random code you write. You need to follow specific coding guidelines, as specified by the tool manufacturer. The coding style you seem to follow looks like C-based. That will not work on an FPGA.

Comment: Where's the clock in your code? Also: input synchronization, button debouching, rising edge detection, etc. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164644/how-to-count-pressed-keys-on-fpga-spartan-board/45165202#45165202).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Entity-statements must be -passive statements, that is, they must not
>   assign values to any signals.

- Don't use shared variables.
- In simulation, variables update immediately upon assignment, as opposed to signals, which are updated only at the end of a simulation cycle. In combinational code, signals immediately take the value of their assignment. In sequential code, signals are used to create flip-flops, which inherently do not immediately take the value of their assignment.
- it is better to use signal+clock instead.

---

Try this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity vending2_mod is
   port(  
      Clock: in std_logic;
      Reset: in std_logic;
      coin : in integer; 
      prod_out : out integer
      );
end vending2_mod;

architecture Behavioral of vending2_mod is
    signal credits : integer := 0; 
begin   
    process(Clock,Reset)
    begin
        if Reset='1' then
            credits <= 0;
        elsif(rising_edge(Clock)) then 
            credits <= credits + coin;  
        end if;
    end process;
    prod_out <= credits;
end Behavioral;
```

See elaborated design: 
[image]

---

Don't try this (synthesis OK, note: You need `clock`):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity vending2_mod is
Port ( 
     coin : in integer; 
     prod_out : out integer);
end vending2_mod;

architecture Behavioral of vending2_mod is
    signal credits : integer := 0; 
begin
    credits <= credits + coin;  
    prod_out <= credits; 
end Behavioral;
```

See elaborated design:
[image]

Comment: I've removed the initial value declaration just before posting the question to try it out if that's the problem, but neither version works.

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of shared variables. They can lead to big problems.

Comment: @Exec: I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't help much. I need the 'credits' value later after a button press, but need to input from the 'coin' port first. The 'prod_out' is used later on after the button press -- I intentionally didn't write out the logic for buttons because I only had a problem with incrementing 'credits'

Edit: It does help some, setting up clock-driven events instead of classic software triggers. I'll be trying out a few things