# VHDL intermittent switch

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I have been trying to create a binary counter in VHDL. Almost everything now works correctly, however I still have a few issues that I have kept me stuck for quite a while.

I am using Quartus Prime Lite, for a DE0-Nano (Altera Cyclone IV).

## Expected behavior

- `i_key(0)` should pause and resume the counter.
- `i_key(1)` should reset the counter to zero, if the counter is running it should stay running and if it is paused it should stay paused.
- `i_dip` selects the speed of the clock.
- `o_led` should display the count in a binary value.

## Issues

- `i_key(0)` is intermittent, sometimes when pressed it works, and other times it doesn't.
- The counter starts running as soon as the board powers on.

Everything else is working as expected.

## What I have tried

Most changes I have tried failed synthesis due to trying to have multiple constant drivers, or because registers didn't hold their values outside the clock edge.

I know the switch works correctly as I connected it directly to an LED and it behaved normally.

I tried adding my own debouncing to the switch in addition to the hardware debouncing, however this didn't help.

```
entity BinaryCounter is
    port (
        i_clock     : in  std_logic;
        i_key       : in    std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        i_dip       : in    std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        o_led       : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end BinaryCounter;

architecture rtl of BinaryCounter is
    
    signal r_tick : std_logic;
    signal r_count : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
    signal r_enabled : std_logic := '0';

begin

    u_clk: entity work.ClockDivider(rtl)
    port map(
        i_clk => i_clock,
        i_enabled => r_enabled,
        i_selector => i_dip,
        o_clk   => r_tick
    );
 
    process (r_tick, i_key) is
    begin
        if i_key(0) = '0' then
            r_enabled <= not r_enabled;
        elsif i_key(1) = '0' then
            r_count <= "00000000";
        elsif rising_edge(r_tick) then
            if r_count = "11111111" then
                r_count <= "00000000";
                r_enabled <= '0';
            else
                r_count <= std_logic_vector( unsigned(r_count) + 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    o_led <= r_count;
    
end rtl;
```

I haven't included the code for the ClockDivider module to try to keep this post shorter since I don't think it is related to the issues I am facing.

Thank you for your patience with this very long question. I hope it made sense..

**Edit:** The debounce logic I used (I can't remember where I got it from)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Debounce is
  Port (
    CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
    x : in  STD_LOGIC;
    DBx : out  STD_LOGIC
  );
end Debounce;

architecture Behavioral of Debounce is
  type State_Type is (S0, S1);
  signal State : State_Type := S0;

  signal DPB, SPB : STD_LOGIC;
  signal DReg : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
begin
  process (CLK, x)
    variable SDC : integer;
    constant Delay : integer := 200000; -- 50000 is 8ms..
  begin
    if CLK'Event and CLK = '1' then
      -- Double latch input signal
      DPB <= SPB;
      SPB <= x;

      case State is
        when S0 =>
          DReg <= DReg(6 downto 0) & DPB;

          SDC := Delay;

          State <= S1;
        when S1 =>
          SDC := SDC - 1;

          if SDC = 0 then
            State <= S0;
          end if;
        when others =>
          State <= S0;
      end case;

      if DReg = X"FF" then
        DBx <= '1';
      elsif DReg = X"00" then
        DBx <= '0';
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

**Edit 2:** I have  discovered that part of my issue is caused by the method I am using to detect key presses. I think this is the cause of both of my issues. Key presses are much more accurately detected with the following:

```
process (key) is
begin
  if falling_edge(key) then
    -- Handle key press...
  end if;
end process;
```

However, I can't figure out how to get this to work since I can't drive the same signal from multiple clocks.

Comment: did you write a test bench?

Comment: @JHBonarius I'm afraid I havn't looked at writing test benches yet as I started learning VHDL yesterday and wanted to get right into it :). I did however make some progress with this issue. I will update the post now.

Comment: What you suggest in your edit 2 is not the correct way to detect a key press. That construct only works in simulation, but the synthesis tool will not create correct synchronous logic from it. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164644/how-to-count-pressed-keys-on-fpga-spartan-board/45165202#45165202)

Comment: It is important to simulate you're code before synthesis. Else you are just using a trial-and-error approach, which is not very intelligent, does not give any insight in your errors and can become very very cumbersome for large designs.

Comment: @JHBonarius Thank you for your advice, I used a two-stage synchronizer to solve the issue as you suggested. If you post that as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: @JHBonarius I have tried to find more information on how to write a test bench, however I have had difficulty in finding any. I would really appreciate it if you could give me pointers on how to find this information.

Comment: Interesting, as the part with `DPB <= SPB; SPB <= x;` effectively already was a two-stage synchronizer.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yeah, but I was still comparing the signal outside of the clock edge if that makes sense.