# VHDL - my FSM does not advance when in a certain state

Tags: rsa, vhdl, fpga, fsm

I'm trying to implement a circuit for a digital signature (RSA) on a FPGA Digilent Basys.
I ended to write down all the components and the top level entity. The Control Unit is formed by a Finit State Machine that controls the whole circuit.
But when I load it on my Basys, it seems to freeze in the State "V_wait_sign".
I can say that because how you can see in the FSM, in the state "V_wait_sign" I puts Leds out to "00100", so just the Led2 is On.

Below the code of the Top Level Entity and the FSM:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;  
entity FirmaDigitale is
    Port ( Clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Buttons : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           Switches : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           Leds : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           Cathodes : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           Anodes : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end FirmaDigitale;

architecture Structural of FirmaDigitale is

    component Comparator32
    Generic(width : Positive := 32);
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (width-1 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (width-1 downto 0);
          Clock  : in  STD_LOGIC;
          Comp_en : in  STD_LOGIC;  -- 1 attivo
           equal : out  STD_LOGIC;
          Notequal : out  STD_LOGIC);
    end component;

    component Decoder_2_4
    Port ( i : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           o : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
    end component;

    component Decoder_Seven_segm
    Port ( Ing : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           Cathodes : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));
    end component;

    component FSM_RSA
    Port ( 
        Clock : in  STD_LOGIC;          -- Clock
        --in

        Start_sign : in  STD_LOGIC; --start sign
        Load : in  STD_LOGIC;          --load 8 bits
        Verify : in  STD_LOGIC;         --start verify signature
        Done : in  STD_LOGIC;           --end message
        Exp_Done : in  STD_LOGIC;       --end exp operation
        Count_hit :in STD_LOGIC;        --signature load
        Count_eq :in STD_LOGIC;         --
        Count_neq :in STD_LOGIC;        --
        --control

        Enable_Hash : out STD_LOGIC;        -- Enable hash '0' attivo         (2colpi)
        Enable_Exp : out STD_LOGIC;     -- Enable exp '1' attivo
        Enable_RegExp : out STD_LOGIC;  -- Enable RegExp '0' attivo
        Enable_sign_reg : out STD_LOGIC; -- Enable sign_reg '0' attivo
        Enable_comp : out STD_LOGIC;        -- Enable Comparator '1' attivo
        Enable_Disp : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);         -- Enable 7segm '0' attivo  

        Leds_step : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
        Mux_sel : out STD_LOGIC;            -- 1 per verifica, 0 per firma
        Mux_disp : out STD_LOGIC;           -- 1 MSB, 0 LSB
        Reset_State : out STD_LOGIC     -- Reset '0' attivo
        );
    end component;

    component HashFunction
    Generic( width : integer := 32; width_reg : integer := 8);
    Port ( CharacterByte : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(width_reg-1 downto 0);
          Clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Reset : in  STD_LOGIC; --0 attivo
          Reg_en : in STD_LOGIC; --0 attivo
           Digest : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(width-1 downto 0)           
          );
    end component;

    component Mux_2n_1n
    Generic(width : integer := 8);
    Port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(width-1 downto 0);
           b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(width-1 downto 0);
           s : in  STD_LOGIC;
           o : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(width-1 downto 0));
    end component;

    component RAsync_2UpNCount_UpCounter
    Generic (width : integer := 2);
    Port ( clock : in  STD_LOGIC;      -- Clock
         reset : in  STD_LOGIC;    -- Segnale di reset 0 attivo
         en : in  STD_LOGIC;       -- Segnale di enable 1 attivo
         count : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (width-1 downto 0) := (others => '0'));  -- conteggio attuale
    end component;

    component SignReg
    Generic( width : integer := 32; width_reg : integer := 8 );
    Port ( SignatureByte : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (width_reg-1 downto 0);
           Reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
          Count_En : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
          hit : out STD_LOGIC;
       Signature : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (width-1 downto 0));
    end component;

    component exponentiator
    Generic (n : integer := 32);
    Port (
        x, y, m: in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
        z: inout std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
        clk, reset, start: in std_logic;
        done: out std_logic 
    );
    end component;

    component display_7_segments
    Generic(
            clock_frequency_in : integer := 50000000;
            clock_frequency_out : integer := 50000000
            );
   Port (  clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset_n : in  STD_LOGIC;
           digits : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           enable : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           dots : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           anodes : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           cathodes : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
    end component;

    component Debouncer_xilinx is 
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           Sig : in  STD_LOGIC; 
           Deb_Sig : out  STD_LOGIC); 
    end component;

    signal temp_exp_done, temp_enable_exp, sel_muxTo_display,   temp_count_hit, temp_sel_EncDec, temp_comp_en, temp_eq, temp_not_eq,   temp_en_RegExp : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal temp_reset_state, temp_enable_hash, temp_en_SignReg : STD_LOGIC := '1';
    signal temp_digest, temp_exp_out, temp_key, temp_sign, Exp_mux_out, RegExp_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal temp_enable_disp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal temp_digits, temp_digits_to_display, temp_fin_digits : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    signal Start_temp, Load_temp, Verify_temp, Done_temp : STD_LOGIC;

begin

    deb_0: Debouncer_xilinx 
        port map(
            CLK => Clock, 
            Sig =>  Buttons(0), 
            Deb_Sig => Start_temp 
            );

    deb_1: Debouncer_xilinx 
        port map(
            CLK => Clock, 
            Sig =>  Buttons(1), 
            Deb_Sig => Load_temp
            );

    deb_2: Debouncer_xilinx 
        port map(
            CLK => Clock, 
            Sig =>  Buttons(2), 
            Deb_Sig => Verify_temp
            );

    deb_3: Debouncer_xilinx 
        port map(
            CLK => Clock, 
            Sig =>  Buttons(3), 
            Deb_Sig => Done_temp
            );

    FSM: FSM_RSA
    Port map ( 
        Clock => Clock,
        Start_sign => Start_temp,
        Load => Load_temp,         --load 8 bits
        Verify => Verify_temp,
        Done => Done_temp,
        Exp_Done => temp_exp_done,
        Count_hit => temp_count_hit,
        Count_eq => temp_eq,
        Count_neq => temp_not_eq,
        --control

        Enable_Hash => temp_enable_hash,
        Enable_Exp => temp_enable_exp,
        Enable_RegExp => temp_en_RegExp,
        Enable_sign_reg => temp_en_SignReg,
        Enable_comp => temp_comp_en,
        Enable_Disp => temp_enable_disp,

        Leds_step => Leds(4 downto 0),
        Mux_sel => temp_sel_EncDec,
        Mux_disp => sel_muxTo_display,
        Reset_State => temp_reset_state
        );

    RegExp : entity work.Generic_RAsync_Register 
        generic map (width => 32)
        port map ( 
            D=> temp_exp_out,
            clock => Clock,
            reset => temp_reset_state,
            en => temp_en_RegExp,
            Q => RegExp_out
            );

    EncriptDecript: exponentiator
    Generic map(n => 32)
    Port map(   x => temp_key,
                y => Exp_mux_out,
                m => x"0000008F", --143, p=11, q=13; pq=143
                z => temp_exp_out,
                clk => Clock,
                reset => not temp_reset_state,
                start => temp_enable_exp,
                done => temp_exp_done
        );

    Leds(7) <= temp_exp_done;

    Mux_Enc_Dec: Mux_2n_1n
    Generic map(width => 32)
    Port map(   a => x"00000071", --113, Chiave Privata
                b => x"00000011", --17, Chiave Pubblica
                s => temp_sel_EncDec,
                o => temp_key
        );

    RegistroFirma: SignReg
    Generic map( width => 32, width_reg => 8 )
    Port map(   SignatureByte => Switches,
                Reset => temp_reset_state,
                Count_En => temp_en_SignReg,
                Clock => Clock,
                hit => temp_count_hit,
                Signature => temp_sign
        );

    Exp_mux : Mux_2n_1n generic map (width => 32)
        port map(
            a => temp_digest,
            b => temp_sign,
            s => temp_sel_EncDec,
            o => Exp_mux_out
            );

    HASH: HashFunction
    Generic map( width => 32, width_reg => 8)
    Port map(   CharacterByte => Switches,
                Clock => Clock,
                Reset => temp_reset_state,
                Reg_en => temp_enable_hash,
                Digest => temp_digest
          );

    Display: display_7_segments
    Generic map( clock_frequency_in => 50000000, clock_frequency_out => 1000 )
    Port map(   clock => Clock,
                reset_n => temp_reset_state,
                digits => temp_digits,
                enable => temp_enable_disp,
                dots => "0000",
                anodes => Anodes,
                cathodes => Cathodes
         );

    Mux_MSB_LSB: Mux_2n_1n
    Generic map(width => 16)
    Port map(   a => RegExp_out(15 downto 0),
                b => RegExp_out(31 downto 16),
                s => sel_muxTo_display,
                o => temp_digits
        );

    Compare: Comparator32
    Generic map( width => 32 )
    Port map(   a => RegExp_out,
                b => temp_sign,
                Clock => Clock,
                Comp_en => temp_comp_en,
                equal => temp_eq,
                Notequal => temp_not_eq
            );

    Leds(6) <= temp_eq;
    Leds(5) <= temp_not_eq;

end Structural;
```

this is the FSM instead:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity FSM_RSA is
    Port ( 
        Clock : in  STD_LOGIC;          -- Clock
        --in

        Start_sign : in  STD_LOGIC; --start sign
        Load : in  STD_LOGIC;          --load 8 bits
        Verify : in  STD_LOGIC;         --start verify signature
        Done : in  STD_LOGIC;           --end message
        Exp_Done : in  STD_LOGIC;       --end exp operation
        Count_hit :in STD_LOGIC;        --signature load
        Count_eq :in STD_LOGIC;         --
        Count_neq :in STD_LOGIC;        --
        --control

        Enable_Hash : out STD_LOGIC;        -- Enable hash '0' attivo (2colpi)
        Enable_Exp : out STD_LOGIC;     -- Enable exp '1' attivo
        Enable_RegExp : out STD_LOGIC;  -- Enable RegExp '0' attivo
        Enable_sign_reg : out STD_LOGIC; -- Enable sign_reg '0' attivo
        Enable_comp : out STD_LOGIC;        -- Enable Comparator '1' attivo
        Enable_Disp : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);         -- Enable 7segm '0' attivo  

        Leds_step : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);

        Mux_sel : out STD_LOGIC;            -- 1 per verifica, 0 per firma
        Mux_disp : out STD_LOGIC;           -- 1 MSB, 0 LSB
        Reset_State : out STD_LOGIC     -- Reset '0' attivo
        );

end FSM_RSA;

architecture Behavioral of FSM_RSA is

-- Definizione dell'insieme degli stati
type State is (Idle, V_wait8, S_wait8, V_Hash,V_waitReg, V_waitH, S_waitH, S_Hash, V_wait_sign, V_decrypt, V_comp, V_reg, S_encrypt, S_dispMSB, S_dispLSB);

-- Definizione dei segnali di "stato" e inizializzazione allo stato iniziale idle
signal Current_State, Next_State : State := Idle;

begin

-- Process per la gestione dell'evoluzione dello stato
state_management : process(Clock)

begin

if falling_edge(Clock) then
    Current_State <= Next_State;
else
    Current_State <= Current_State;
end if;

end process;

-- Process per la gestione della FSM
FSM : process(Current_State, Start_sign, Load, Verify, Done, Exp_Done, Count_eq, Count_neq, Count_hit)
begin

case Current_State is

  --macchina in attesa di comandi. Tutti i registri disabilitati
    when Idle => 
            Enable_Hash <= '1'; 
            Enable_Exp <= '0';
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '0';
            Mux_sel <= '0';
            Mux_disp <= '0';
            Leds_step <= "00000";

        if (Verify = '1') then
                Next_State <= V_wait8;
            else 
                if ( Start_sign ='1') then
                    Next_state <= S_wait8;
                    else
                        Next_state <= Idle;
                end if;
        end if;

        when S_encrypt => 
            Enable_Hash <= '1';
            Enable_Exp <= '1';  -- abilito
            Enable_RegExp <= '0';  -- abilito
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '1'; 
            Mux_sel <= '0'; --decript M_h**d modn
            Mux_disp <= '0';
            Leds_step <= "00010";

            if (Exp_Done = '1') then
                    Next_State <= S_dispMSB;
                else
                    Next_state <= S_encrypt;
            end if;

        when S_dispLSB => 
            Enable_Hash <= '1';
            Enable_Exp <= '0';  
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';  
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "1111"; -- abilito
            Reset_State  <= '1'; 
            Mux_sel <= '0'; 
            Mux_disp <= '0'; --LSB

            if (Done = '1') then
                    Next_State <= Idle;
                else
                    Next_state <=S_dispLSB;
            end if;

        when S_dispMSB => 
            Enable_Hash <= '1';
            Enable_Exp <= '0';  
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';  
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "1111"; -- abilito
            Reset_State  <= '1'; 
            Mux_sel <= '0'; 
            Mux_disp <= '1'; --MSB

            if (Load = '1') then
                    Next_State <= S_dispLSB;
                else
                    Next_state <=S_dispMSB;
            end if;

        when S_waitH => 
           Enable_Hash <= '1'; --disabilito tutto
            Enable_Exp <= '0';
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '1';
            Mux_sel <= '0';

            if( Load = '0') then
                Next_State <= S_wait8;
            else
                Next_State <= S_waitH;
            end if;


        when S_Hash => 
           Enable_Hash <= '0'; -- abilito
            Enable_Exp <= '0';
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '1';
            Mux_sel <= '0';
            Mux_disp <= '0';

          Next_State <= S_waitH;

        when S_wait8 =>         
            Enable_Hash <= '1'; --disabilito tutto
            Enable_Exp <= '0';
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '1';
            Mux_sel <= '0';
            Mux_disp <= '0';
            Leds_step <= "00001";

            if (Done = '1') then
                Next_State <= S_encrypt;
            else 
                if ( Load = '1') then
                    Next_state <= S_Hash;
                    else 
                        Next_state <= S_wait8;
                end if;
            end if;

        when V_comp => 
            Enable_Hash <= '1';
            Enable_Exp <= '0';  
            Enable_RegExp <= '0';
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '1';  -- abilito
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '1'; 
            Mux_sel <= '1'; --decript M_h**e modn
            Mux_disp <= '0';
            Leds_step <= "10000";

            if (Count_eq = '1' OR Count_neq ='1') then
                if (Done = '1') then
                    Next_State <= Idle;
                end if;
            end if;

        when V_decrypt => 
            Enable_Hash <= '1';
            Enable_Exp <= '1';  -- abilito
            Enable_RegExp <= '0';  -- abilito
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '1'; 
            Mux_sel <= '1'; --decript M_h**e modn
            Mux_disp <= '0';
            Leds_step <= "01000";

            if (Exp_Done = '1') then
                    Next_State <= V_comp;
                else
                    Next_state <= V_decrypt;
            end if;


    when V_Reg => 
           Enable_Hash <= '1'; 
            Enable_Exp <= '0';
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';
            Enable_sign_reg <= '0'; -- abilito
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "1111";
            Reset_State  <= '1';
            Mux_sel <= '0';
            Mux_disp <= '0';

            if( Count_hit = '1') then
                Next_State <= V_decrypt;
            else
                Next_State <= V_waitReg;
            end if;


    when V_waitReg => 
           Enable_Hash <= '1'; --disabilito tutto
            Enable_Exp <= '0';
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '1';
            Mux_sel <= '0';
            Mux_disp <= '0';

            if( Load = '0') then
                Next_State <= V_wait_sign;
            else
                Next_State <= V_waitReg;
            end if;


    when V_wait8 =>         
            Enable_Hash <= '1'; --disabilito tutto
            Enable_Exp <= '0';
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '1';
            Mux_sel <= '0';
            Mux_disp <= '0';

            if (Done = '1') then
                    Next_State <= V_wait_sign;
                else 
                    if ( Load = '1') then
                        Next_state <= V_Hash;
                        else 
                            Next_state <= V_wait8;
                    end if;
            end if;


    when V_Hash => 
           Enable_Hash <= '0'; -- abilito
            Enable_Exp <= '0';
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '1';
            Mux_sel <= '0';
            Mux_disp <= '0';

          Next_State <= V_waitH;


    when V_waitH => 
           Enable_Hash <= '1'; --disabilito tutto
            Enable_Exp <= '0';
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '1';
            Mux_sel <= '0';

            if( Load = '0') then
                Next_State <= V_wait8;
            else
                Next_State <= V_waitH;
            end if;


    when V_wait_sign => 
            Enable_Hash <= '1';  --disabilito tutto
            Enable_Exp <= '0';
            Enable_RegExp <= '1';
            Enable_sign_reg <= '1';
            Enable_comp <= '0';
            Enable_Disp <= "0000";
            Reset_State  <= '1';
            Mux_sel <= '0';
            Leds_step <= "00100";

        if (Load = '1') then -- AND Count_hit = '0') then
            Next_State <= V_reg;    
--      else
--          if (Count_hit = '1') then
--              Next_state <= V_decrypt;
            else
                Next_state <= V_wait_sign;
            --end if;
        end if; 

    end case;       
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I can't understand what could be wrong. When I try the testbench, it seems to work. 
But tjan on the FPGA it freezes on that state. It is as if he did not receive the signal "Count Hit" from the "SignReg". But I'm not sure about that

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Note Leds_step is not assigned in each Current_State case statement choice, implying latches. Consider simulating your design.

Comment: Do you confirm the deb_1's output?

Comment: Please show the code of `Debouncer_xilinx`. This smells like a metastability issue. And we need the other code including the test bench to replicate your issue.

Comment: Hi, to see the other code, I uploaded the whole project here.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bdP9O0HInMKPGZJy_6jxlVnyrGndEYGj

I edited a couple of things in the meantime.. now seems to be freezed in the state "V_decrypt"

Comment: I don't think `debouncer_xilinx` is a good component. Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164644/how-to-count-pressed-keys-on-fpga-spartan-board/45165202#45165202).

Comment: Maxim has [APPLICATION NOTE 287](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/287) that addresses key bounce with a counter as JHBonarius answer advocates. Bounce can get longer as membrane switches age for example. Your edge detector with three successive flip flops at 100 MHz doesn't appear adequate for bounces on the order of ten milliseconds. You could probably model a couple of different bouncy key events to check out their effect on FSM_RSA.

Comment: Thanks JHBonarius. I used your debouncer and now it works fine!
I just receive this error:
`Line 17: Value -9223 is out of target constraint range 1 to 2147483647`
Than putting a minus in `constant settle_time_in_clocks : positive := integer(-(real(clock_frequency) * settle_time) / 1 sec ); -- MHz to ms` 
Ise go on until he creates the .bit file.
Now I think I have a problem with the comparator.. I think he didn't compare in a right way.. 
I upload the project corrected here: [Project Dir](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e-nANHDiTDMhX7xlj2AZYzGhRokuRgSZ)

Comment: I made varoius test on the Fpga. This is what happens. The comparator should turn On the Leds(6) when equal and Leds(7) when not equal. The Leds(6) turns on just when I insert all 0s in the State V_wait_sign, that insert, 8bits for time, the value of switches in the SignReg. The other times is only the Leds(7) to turn on, so not equal after the comparison. EDIT: I just found an error, in b input of comprator, it should be linked the signal temp_digest, so the output of the Hash function.
Infact I have to compare the hashed message and the decrypted signature. But now it's every time not equal