# VHDL. Checking switch to reset a counter. elsif works, if doesnt

Tags: vhdl, counter, reset

Can someone please explain why this works:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity Switches_LEDs is
Port ( switches : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0);
LEDs : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
CLK_100MHz : in STD_LOGIC
);
end Switches_LEDs;
architecture Behavioral of Switches_LEDs is
    signal counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(29 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
clk_proc: process(CLK_100MHz)
    begin
    LEDs <= counter(29 downto 22);
    if (switches(0) = '0') then
        counter <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(CLK_100MHz) then
        counter <= counter+1;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

and not this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity Switches_LEDs is
Port ( switches : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0);
LEDs : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
CLK_100MHz : in STD_LOGIC
);
end Switches_LEDs;
architecture Behavioral of Switches_LEDs is
    signal counter : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(29 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
clk_proc: process(CLK_100MHz)
    begin
    LEDs <= counter(29 downto 22);
    if (switches(0) = '0') then
        counter <= (others => '0');
    end if;
    if rising_edge(CLK_100MHz) then
        counter <= counter+1;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Also, why don't I need to "declare" the switches in the clk_proc? 
Got a warning about the question having a lot of code in... so... adding words.

Comment: (a) because signal assignment semantics (aka "last assignment wins") (b) because the declaration is in the port statement in the entity.

Comment: Both descriptions are wrong regarding `LEDs <= ...` Your simulation model behaves differently then the synthesized results will work in your chip ... You should not use package `STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED` anymore!

Comment: Two independent if statements don't infer an edge sensitive register with an asynchronous reset in synthesis. In simulation the answer to why is found in IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement, there's only one slot for any particular simulation time in a projected output waveform (as Brian comments "last assignment wins"). Show any error messages and/or provide an indication of 'why this works', 'and not this' is determined ("It doesn't work" is not a problem statement - provide a complete [mcve]).

Comment: Probably your `switches` is connected to external mechanical switches. That will cause metastablility issues. You need to synchronize and debounce the inputs. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45165202/6717178) for some code examples.

Answer (score 1):

In a process last assignment wins.
In your code neither **counter** nor **switches** are in sensitivity list so I would expect some unexpected behavior.

If you need asynchronous reset then you should use template like this:

```
process(clk, reset)
begin
  if reset condition then

  elsif clock event then

  end if;
end process;
```

If you need synchronous reset then:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if clock event then
    if reset condition then

    else

    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

You should move **LEDs <= counter(29 downto 22);** probably out of process too.

Comment: "You should move `LEDs <= counter(29 downto 22);` probably out of process too." <-- not required. Could be that you want double registering due to output timing. Or to minimize the fan-out in very high switching speed applications.

Comment: ... and with regards to "last assignment wins", you could also have the synchronous reset as: `process(clk) begin if [clock event] then [normal assignment]; if [reset condition] then [reset assignment]; end if; end if; end process;`. Thus omitting the `else` statement.