# VHDL: Are these two equivalent?

Tags: vhdl

when I synthesize the circuit with code 1 the circuit doesn't work correctly. if I use the second one it works fine. Under simulation there is no difference between the two. The up_key/down_key are both push buttons and they are debounced.

code 1:

```
when wait0 =>
    if (up_key = '1' or down_key = '1') then    
        state_next <= wait0;
    else
        state_next <= idle;
    end if;
```

---

code 2:

```
when wait0 =>
    if (up_key = '1') then  
        state_next <= wait0;
    elsif (down_key = '1') then
        state_next <= wait0;
    else
        state_next <= idle;
    end if;
```

---

Complete Code: Here is the complete code. It is a simple counter that displays the count on a seven segment display.

One issue with my code is with indexes. I defined disp7_type range from 0 to 9 but in the assignment $hex0 <= disp7(to_integer(counter_reg))$
, counter_reg can reach a value of 10, which is out of range. I didn't notice this when I was doing simulation, but today I rechecked it again and I saw the issue....akhh...unforgettable mistake..

I don't have any issues now when I use code 1. However, I still don't understand what made code 2 resolves this issue, it shouldn't!!!. I also still don't understand why the seven segment display hangs/stopped responding?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity hex_disp is
    port(
        CLOCK_50: in std_logic;
        key: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        hex0: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
        );
end entity;

architecture demo of hex_disp is
    type disp7_type is array (0 to 9) of std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    constant disp7: disp7_type := ("1000000","1111001","0100100","0110000","0011001",
                                                "0010010","0000011","1111000","0000000","0011000");
    
    signal clk, reset: std_logic;
    signal counter_next, counter_reg: unsigned(3 downto 0) := "0000";
    
    signal up_key: std_logic;
    signal down_key: std_logic;
    
    type states is (idle, up, down, wait0);
    signal state_next, state_reg: states;
    
    
begin
    clk <= CLOCK_50;
    reset <= not key(0);
    up_key <= not key(2);
    down_key <= not key(3);
    
    
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            state_reg <= idle;
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            state_reg <= state_next;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    process(state_reg, up_key, down_key, counter_reg)
    begin
        counter_next <= counter_reg;
        state_next <= state_reg;
        case state_reg is
            when idle =>
                if down_key = '1' then
                    state_next <= down;
                end if;
                if up_key = '1' then
                    state_next <= up;
                end if;
            when up =>
                counter_next <= counter_reg + 1;
                if up_key = '1' then
                    state_next <= wait0;
                else 
                    state_next <= idle;
                end if;
            when down =>
                counter_next <= counter_reg - 1;
                if down_key = '1' then
                    state_next <= wait0;
                else
                    state_next <= idle;
                end if;
            when wait0 =>
                if (up_key = '1' or down_key = '1') then    
                    state_next <= wait0;
                else
                    state_next <= idle;
                end if;     
        end case;
    end process;
    
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            counter_reg <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            counter_reg <= counter_next;
            if counter_reg = 10 then
                counter_reg <= (others => '0');
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    hex0 <= disp7(to_integer(counter_reg));
    
end architecture;
```

Comment: They appear equivolent. Any differences would be in code you havent shown.

Comment: @Tricky, Thanx a lot. I have uploaded the complete code (this is my first question on stackoverflow).....Is it correct that the issue is caused by the way I wrote/handled buttons in state idle ?.

Comment: What is the issue when testing Code 1 in hardware? You state that it doesn't work correctly. What exactly do you mean? How do you know it's not working correctly?

Comment: @Laburtz thank you. The seven segment display hangs/doesn't work anymore even if I press one of the buttons. I think I just found out what the problem is with my code (this is my speculation since I am new to VHDL/FPGA). I think the issue is in my last process where I reset the counter_reg to 0 after it reaches 10. It seems that I am updating my counter_reg and then resetting it in same clock cycle. If that is correct I still don't understand why if I use code 2, then things will work correctly.

Comment: @violent.ic There's no issue with your code updating `counter_reg` and then potentially resetting it. Do note that when you do `counter_reg = 10` you're not checking if you set it to 10, you're checking if it's previous state was 10 (since it's a signal, not a variable).

Comment: @Darhuuk thank you for your clarification. I see I did a mistake in indexing: disp7_type has a range from 0 to 9. It cannot take 10.

Comment: What tool/platform are you using (and what version)? On a side note: You should look at using a synchronized reset. But that's not the issue (i think).

Comment: Have you debounced the keys/switches? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45165202).

Comment: @ JHBonarius Thank you. I use Altera de2, Cyclone II 2c35---Quartus  version 13.0.1. It is actually quite an old board..The push-buttons are denounced by a Schmitt trigger circuit.

Comment: An external circuit? And did you synchronize the inputs in VHDL? (Did you read my link?) Not doing so will cause all kinds of undefined behavior.

Comment: @ JHBonarius. Yes external circuit. The inputs are not synchronized  (I am currently  reading reading your link) , and I think it is very important information. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
counter_reg <= counter_next;
if counter_reg = 10 then
    counter_reg <= (others => '0');
end if;
```

to

```
counter_reg <= counter_next;
if counter_next= 10 then
    counter_reg <= (others => '0');
end if;
```

The signal "counter_reg" gets updated on each clock cycle (at the end of the process). So it will still hold the value of the previous clock cycle for the comparison. Only in the next clock cycle counter_reg will be set from 10 to 0.

disp7 has no index 10 so this might upset something. It's definately something to fix.

Not sure, if this is the solution. I would write this as a comment, but miss some reputation :-/